# How to download Vim script on the command-line?

Tags: vim, download

Whenever I want to install a new Vim script on the Linux server I'm working on, my typical workflow is as the following:

1. surf the plugin's homepage in Vim
   online using FireXXXX
2. download a right version of the
   plugin to my laptop by click some highlighted link
3. upload the downloaded plugin from my
   laptop to Linux server using WinSCP

which is really inconvenient. I don't know what is the magic behind this: I mean for the same hyperlink I click it in web browser. I can let you download it but use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) plus the hyperlink in Linux command-line will end up with nothing but an error indication. Hyperlink in the web browser.   Otherwise I can get the link in web browser and then use Wget or some similar tool to actually do the downloding.

I try new cool Vim scripts quite ofte , so you can imagine my dismay when I have to repeat the tedious action all the time. What are some tips which can let me download the Vim scripts in a more "professional" way?

---

Post edit:

My problem is not find a tool like Wget or [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). The problem I met is quite specific; to use these tools to download a Vim script. Let's take
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30 as an example.

It's the normal place where one can get the script, at least for me. But I can't find an working URL from this page that can feed to Wget.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example URL and indicated exactly what problems you are having with *wget*. It (or something like it, e.g. cURL, etc.) is the usual solution to “command line downloading”.

Comment: are there permissions issues with the linux server? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Chris Johensn and kajaco:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30
I can't find the url for the script in the above link that is my problem.

Comment: The URL for that script seems fairly obvious to me. It is the first link in the table at the bottom of the page. That is what you click to download via a web browser, is it not? Again, what problem are you having with *wget*? The URL `http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9196` (for the 1.13 version on the page you gave) works fine for me with *wget* 1.12 and *curl* 7.20.0.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at wget http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Answer (score 2):

Answering to the specific case of python_fn.vim. The links provided on the page work just fine in wget - they just get the wrong name (download_script.php?src_id=9196). If this is causing you troubles, you can use wget's -O. As in:

`wget -O python_fn.vim http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9196`

Comment: The `--content-disposition` option of *wget* will cause the downloaded files to use the server-provided name like web browsers do. Also, you may want to quote the URL (I prefer single quotes) so that the shell does not try to expand it as a glob (since it has `?` in it; depending on the shell and the options that are active, globs that do not match anything sometimes expand to an empty string, and sometimes cause errors).

Comment: That's very useful, I actually skimmed the man page to find out if there was such a feature, but apparently not thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps
[GetLatestVimScripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=642)
is something for you?

Answer (score 2):

From page 'http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30' , you can find the download url is 'http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9196'.
This step is quite easy.

I think the really problem for you is after

```
wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9196
```

you got file 'download_script.php?src_id=9196' and you thought the download failed..

Actually the plugins has downloaded successfully as 'download_script.php?src_id=9196', just rename it as 'python_fn.vim' or add '-O python_fn.vim' for wget.

Answer (score 1):

[Comparison of open source download tools](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html) (most of them command line, including wget tronpxs already mentioened)

Answer (score 1):

To download the file you've mentioned in post edit:

```
%> wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9196
%> mv download_script.php?src_id=9196 python_fn.vim
```

The general algorithm is:

1. go to desired vim script page
2. locate a table with downloads in the
   bottom which looks like

package       | script version | date | Vim version | user | release notes

3. copy hyperlink of the desired file
   and feed it to wget
4. rename resulting file to what you
   have seen in package column on
   download page

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/bin/vim-addons
```

in Ubuntu, but I actually use pathogen and github or

```
.../download_script.php?src_i=...
```

with vimballs and then gunzip and mkdir, and `:UseVimball`

Answer (score 0):

Use a text-based browser, like w3m.

```
w3m http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30
```

It won't have any problems with redirection, so pointing it to the script download url:

```
w3m http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9196
```

Will present you with the option of downloading the file.